# Problem encounter while searching From and To dates in C# MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

While i try to search by one date From: 2/27/2020  and keeping my Date to : field as null..
I m seeing all the records the day after 2/27/2020 those all records  are being displayed here..I only need the data of 2/27/2020 only..
Here's how my controller is [image: Controller]

Here's how i see my result after i put from date: 2/27/2020 i am getting data of today's date also.
[image: Output]

Please Help me to solve this mistake.

Comment: Just check if _dateFrom_ has value while _dateTo_ has no value. In that case set _dateTo_ equal to _dateFrom_ then run the query

Comment: no sir your this idea didnt work here.. All i see is Blank Result

Comment: I think your code is fine as the UI says about `DateFrom` means user want to check all those records starting from that date if the user wants to see only one specific date records he needs to put the date value in `DateTo` field also,
otherwise, it is possible to show only `DateFrom` records by adding additional check but user will not able to see onwards records by putting only one date value.

Comment: If your database columns contains also the Time part then _dataTo_ should be _dateFrom_ **plus** 1439 minutes, but probably you should consider the comment above from @UmairAnwaar.

Comment: @HemantAcharya ASP.NET is a web framework, it doesn't query anything. What ORM are you using, where are the ORM's queries? What is `Get()`? There's no such method in EF or NHibernate.

Comment: Also `tableId.HasValue` etc aren't needed can only cause bugs. If you don't want a specific filter condition, just don't add it. LINQ allows you to chain multiple `Where()` calls

Answer (score 0):

If your client's required this functionality(client always win) you can do this by little change in the filter logic like this.

```
 (!waiterId.HasValue || x.OrderDetails.Any(y => y.WaiterId == waiterId && y.DataStatus ==(int)eDataStatus.Active)) && 
 (
    (dateFrom.HasValue && dateTo.HasValue && x.Date >= dateFrom && (x.Date) <= (dateTo) ) 
   || 
   ((dateFrom.HasValue && (x.Date) = (dateFrom))  || (dateTo.HasValue &&  (x.Date) = (dateTo)) ) 
 ) &&
 (!floorId.HasValue || x.Table.FloorId == floorId )&&
```

also, consider the @steve comment if time exists in the database column you will need to pars DateTime into the date for both filter field and database column

For the reference, you can remove time by using `System.Data.Entity.DbFunctions.TruncateTime()`